# Missing trailing slash for path variable

Tags: cmake

I have the following variable in cmake:

```
set(LOCAL_DROP "~/mydrop/" CACHE PATH "Path to drop folder.")
```

and it works as expected. Same if I change it with cmake-gui.

But if I try to set it with `cmake  -DLOCAL_DROP=/my/path/to/folder/`  the trailing slash is missing.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's done on purpose by CMake itself. You can suppress it by changing variable type  to `STRING`, but what's the problem with this behavior?

Comment: Problem is the extra slash if I use the variable. In case the variable LOCAL_DROP is empty, the slash points to root directory: `set(LibRootFolder "${LOCAL_DROP}/${LibNameVersion}/${LibPlatform}")`

Comment: To workaround this you can check if `LOCAL_DROP` is empty and conditionally set it to `.`.